# Angular Adminlte - LoadscriptDirective Issue in deployment

Tags: angular, adminlte

I used AdminLte template for my Angular 7 App.

[image: loadscript]

In my App Module

```
import { LoadscriptDirective } from './directives/loadscript.directive';
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
LoadscriptDirective,
```

In my directive.module.ts

I have:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoadscriptDirective } from './loadscript.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
LoadscriptDirective
 ],
  imports: [
CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
LoadscriptDirective
  ]
})
export class DirectivesModule { }
```

iN MY Angularcli, when I run

> ng build --prod

I got this error:

[image: loadscripterror]

> ERROR in : Type LoadscriptDirective in app/directives/loadscript.directive.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in /app/app.module.ts and DirectivesModule in app/directives/directives.module.ts! Please consider moving LoadscriptDirective in app/directives/loadscript.directive.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in app/app.module.ts and DirectivesModule in app/directives/directives.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes LoadscriptDirective in app/directives/loadscript.directive.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in app/app.module.ts and DirectivesModule in app/directives/directives.module.ts.

How do I resolve this isssue